# How do I predict if a user bought an item

Tags: machine-learning, model, classification, prediction

Here is my problem statement. I have a user dataset which has user_id, has_bought (0- if not bought and 1 if bought) and 10 user features. I have another dataset which has item_id, 3 item features and user_id. It has items only bought by the users in the user dataset. what machine learning model can I user to predict 'has_bought' by using these two datasets?

I understood that it is a classification problem, but how can I integrate user features with item features and train a prediction model?

Thanks,
Keerthi

Comment: Did you mean something like collaborative filtering? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering

Comment: Hi Bghaak, Thanks for the reply. I don't want to recommend new items but just predict for the given dataset.

Comment: Do you need to predict whether a certain item would be bought from a given user?

Comment: yes, exactly. Thanks

Comment: Basically almost every classification method would work (example Random Forest) where one instance includes the user features and all the item features of bought product. 
There are many optimization techniques, but this question is way to broad.
You should first try something and ask specific information, but not questions of the type "How can I do XYZ".

Best Regards

Comment: But can I combine user features and item feature and train a classification model on all the features with 'has_bought' as label?